# Ensuring a variable is always cached in Spark and never gets evicted

Tags: caching, apache-spark, serialization

I have a non-serializable object and I need that object to be 100% cached in memory all the time. However as spark job requires more execution memory due to load increase it tries to evict the cached object into disk and since the object is not serializable I will get "task not serializable" exception. Is there anyway to force spark to keep my object in cache all the time?

Answer (score 1):

This is not the right direction. Even if it's cached, it may also need to be serialized when a remote node is trying to fetch it. If you just want to always cache it in executor side, you can use companion object in Scala or singleton pattern in Java to lazily create them as static objects.